# scheduled notification

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have to develop android app which must schedule different notifications in a distinct date that is in the future. I have the idea to not schedule using AlarmManager in an Activity class for all notifications in the same time in my app but instead using a service in the app that can each 24h(= per day) verify if there is one or more than one notification to show today for the user of my app. My datas are many dates in the future that specify the time when the user must be notified. What is the best practice ? And you 're welcome if you have another kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to implement a service for alarms like you describe. AlarmManager was made for this purpose. If you were to implement a service, first you would be taking resources 24/7, and the user isn't going to like that. Second, how are you going to notify the user if the device is asleep? It seems overly complicated. Is there a reason you don't want to use AlarmManager?

Comment: Hi @Samuel,Thank you for your answer. You're right. My idea isn't efficient like that. Normally, I use AlarmManager with an Activity but i notice that when my app stops (for example by force close in the settings/Manage Application to test if, for exemple, the system close my app because of needing memory), i'm no longer notified. Have you some tips ? Thank you

Comment: Hasina, there will always be a chance that that can happen, but even if you used a service, the user could stop your service or Android could close it because of low memory. I don't know that there is any way to avoid those things. Using the alarm manager is supposed to keep your alarm around until the device is shut down.

Comment: So do you know a way how we can in Android app, that is in background, intercept that the device is being shut down ? Because in the app, i want change some data value in Sqlite DB when this happens.

Comment: There is an intent you can receive for that. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN